# swift init optional array wrapping

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

Hi I'm new in swift I'm trying to have an Array that is optional, some times that is null, I don't know what is the proper syntax, here is the code

```
public final class Content: ResponseObject,ResponseCollection {
public let created: String
public let name: String
public let children: [Content]?

@objc required public init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
    self.name = representation.valueForKeyPath("name") as! String
    self.created = representation.valueForKeyPath("created") as! String       
    self.children = Content.collection(response:response, representation: representation.valueForKeyPath("children")!)
}

@objc public static func collection(#response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Content] {
    var contents: [Content] = []

    if let representation = representation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for contentRepresentation in representation {
            if let content = Content(response: response, representation: contentRepresentation) {
                contents.append(content)
            }
        }
    }

    return contents
}
```

Children can be nil sometimes, but it crash when is null.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.children = Content.collection(response:response, representation: representation.valueForKeyPath("children")!)
```

With the `!`, because you are forcing optional unwrapping.. so if "children" path does not exist, the app will crash.

**UPDATE:**

The signature for `valueForKeyPath(_:)` is:

```
func valueForKeyPath(_ keyPath: String) -> AnyObject?
```

which returns an optional. I would suggest you to do:

```
@objc required public init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
    if let namePath = representation.valueForKeyPath("name") as? String, createdPath = representation.valueForKeyPath("created") as? String, childrenPath = representation.valueForKeyPath("children") as? String {
        self.name = namePath
        self.created = createdPath
        self.children = Content.collection(response:response, representation: childrenPath)
    }
    else {
        println("name path, created path, or children path does not exists")
    }
}
```

replace <"ClassType"> by the correct class type.

Comment: Yeah I want the property children optional, some times is nil, how I can do that??

Comment: that doesn't work, because is inside init method , I just try it and I get compiler error message

Comment: Content.swift:24:27: Variable 'self.children' used before being initialized

Comment: you're not calling super.init

Comment: nop. I also try the last one that you update, same problem if the var is inside condition I get that error

Comment: I think if I change to var I can do it, but I don't know, must be different way of doing this I have this now     ```public var children: [Content]``` and then ```self.children = []
        if let childrenPath = representation.valueForKeyPath("children") as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            self.children = Content.collection(response:response, representation: childrenPath)
        }
        else {
            println("Children path does not exists")
        }
```

Comment: yes, if you turn them into var, they should work. There's no harm for them to be var in this case.